# plt.show() does not display anything

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using Jupyter notebook and I'm trying to plot graphs using subplots based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAkOnV1-lIg&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcOdF96TBtRtuQksErCEBYZ&index=3&ab_channel=sentdex):

I just tried everything in the same format as shown in the video.
When I do a simple plot,

For example,

```
plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,4,6])
```

It gives a normal result.

[image]

But, when I try to create two axis, like this,

```
ax1.plot(df.index, df['APT.AX'])
ax2.plot(df.index, df['A2M.AX'])
```

It just gives the following result:

```
Out: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1ab0e0db8b0>]
```

And when I enter `plt.show()`, it just does nothing.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `matplotlib` using conda. I have tried by adding %matplotlib inline before using it.

Anything I can do here?

Comment: add `%matplotlib inline` on the first line

Comment: Hi I tried doing that. First line as in the import line?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. Use show() in the next line or plt.show()